# Searching array of structures for match and output

Tags: c, arrays, string, structure, strcmp

I have an array of structures. I need the user to input a name then search the structure of a match then output that information. I am using strcmp to compare the string for a match. So, far no matter what the user enters the entire list prints out.

I am using a for-loop to cycle through the array to find the matching name. I then used an if statement with strcmp to compare the strings for a match. Instead of printing only the matching string, it is printing the the entire list.

```
 printf("Enter city name:\n");
 scanf("%s", city);

 //change city to lower case before comparison
 for(i=0; i<strlen(city); i++)
   city[i] = low(city[i]);

 //fp = fopen(outfile, "w");
 printf("The population density is:\n");
 for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   if ( strcmp(city, veg[i].name)) {
     density = veg[i].population / veg[i].area;
     printf("%s  %.2f\n", veg[i].name, density );
   }
 }
```

The user should enter a name of a city held in the structure. The loop should go through the structure until it finds the match and output the city name with the population density. However, the if statement doesnt seem to be doing anything. The entire list prints, rather than just the match.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` returns 0 if the strings are equal and nonzero if they are not.  (Mnemonic: think of `strcmp` as *subtracting* the strings and returning the result of the subtraction).  Hence your `if` block will execute only when `veg[i].name` does *not* equal `city`.

You probably want to write

```
if (strcmp(city, veg[i].name) == 0) { ...
```

Some people write

```
if (!strcmp(city, veg[i].name)) { ...
```

but I personally find this less clear.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have your print function within the for for loop therefore your print function will be called multiple times(10 in your case).. when it comes to the matching check if strcmp(your strings) is equal to 0.. if they are then it is a match, if not then it is not a match. so check if strcmp is equal to zero and take the print function out of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` returns integer. Check description here

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp

In your code if statement you should check that the value is equal to `0` instead keeping directly `strcmp`.

Hope it will work.